# adding column values of a drived table

Tags: mysql

I need to select entries that have no duplicate by multiple columns, Last_name, First_Name. I use COUNT(First_Name), as part of the SELECT, to verify how many entries result.

```
SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, COUNT(First_Name) 
FROM table_of_people_and_their_data 
GROUP BY LAST_Name HAVING COUNT(First_Name) = 1;
```

-- gives all individual entries and a count of the entries as a check.

```
SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, COUNT(First_Name) 
FROM table_of_people_and_their_data 
GROUP BY LAST_Name HAVING COUNT(First_Name) > 1;
```

-- gives all entries with duplicates and a count of the duplicates.

all from the same table.

table_of_people_and_their_data has many columns. Only sorting by first and last name.

> Now, count(table_of_people_and_their_data) produces 957 rows.
>                                     
>                   count of first query = 1 produces 120 rows.
>                               
>                  count of second query > 1 produces 359 rows.
>                                                      
>                             Total of these query is 479 rows.           120 + 359 = 479
>
> I assume the results with duplicate rows has a 837 row count.  957 - 120 = 837

The queries I have given produce a table that reads with three columns, Last_Name,First_Name,COUNT(First_Name)

Something like:

```
        Last_Name | First_Name | Count
          Jack        Frost        3
         Sally        Soft         4
```

and so on. I figure if I add the Count column I could prove the previous queries as all the results of the Count column added up should be 837.

How can I achieve this in one query; use query given above modified something like:

```
SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, SUM(mycount) 
FROM COUNT(First_Name) mycount FROM table_of_people_and_their_data 
GROUP BY LAST_Name HAVING COUNT(First_Name) > 1;
```

I have tried many variations on using alias and drived tables. Most my errors have come back ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Show us sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:-

```
Select   srce,first_name,last_name,Obs,CumulativeTotal
from
(
select   srce,first_name,last_name,Obs,rn,@rt:=@rt+Obs as CumulativeTotal
from
(
SELECT  1 as srce,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COUNT(*) as Obs, @rn:=@rn + 1 as rn
FROM        TBL_BORROWERS , (select @rn:=0) rb
group   by  first_name, last_name having (count(*) = 1)
) s
,(select @rt:=0) rt
) t

union all
select   srce,'Unique Csutomers', '' ,count(distinct first_name,last_name),count(distinct first_name,last_name) 
from
(
select   2 as srce,first_name,last_name,Obs,rn,@rt:=@rt+Obs as CumulativeTotal
from
(
SELECT  1 as srce,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COUNT(*) as Obs, @rn:=@rn + 1 as rn
FROM        TBL_BORROWERS , (select @rn:=0) rb
group   by  first_name, last_name having (count(*) = 1)
) s
,(select @rt:=0) rt
) t

union all
Select   srce,first_name,last_name,Obs,CumulativeTotal
from
(
select   srce,first_name,last_name,Obs,rn,@rt1:=@rt1+Obs as CumulativeTotal
from
(
SELECT  3 as srce,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COUNT(*) as Obs, @rn1:=@rn1 + 1 as rn
FROM        TBL_BORROWERS , (select @rn1:=0) rn
group   by  first_name, last_name having (count(*) > 1)
) s
,(select @rt1:=0) rt1

) t

union all
select   srce,'Duplicate Customers', '' ,count(distinct first_name,last_name),count(distinct first_name,last_name) 
from
(
select   4 as srce,first_name,last_name,Obs,rn,@rt:=@rt+Obs as CumulativeTotal
from
(
SELECT  1 as srce,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,COUNT(*) as Obs, @rn:=@rn + 1 as rn
FROM        TBL_BORROWERS , (select @rn:=0) rb
group   by  first_name, last_name having (count(*) > 1)
) s
,(select @rt:=0) rt
) t


UNION    
SELECT  9 as srce,'Distinct Customers' as first_name,'' as last_name,
            COUNT(DISTINCT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME),
            COUNT(DISTINCT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME)
FROM        TBL_BORROWERS
UNION    
SELECT  10 as srce,'Total Rows' as first_name,'' as last_name,
            COUNT(*),
            COUNT(*)
FROM        TBL_BORROWERS
```